# How to create rangeselectors buttons for different periods on the plot - plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm looking for a way to automatically create buttons for different time periods in my dataset. As example from here shows it can be done using the following code:

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

# Download some data
getSymbols(Symbols = c("AAPL", "MSFT"), from = '2018-01-01', to = '2020-01-01')
ds <- data.frame(Date = index(AAPL), AAPL[,6], MSFT[,6])

fig <- plot_ly(ds, x = ~Date)
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~AAPL.Adjusted, name = "Apple")
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~MSFT.Adjusted, name = "Microsoft")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Stock Prices",
  xaxis = list(
    rangeselector = list(
      buttons = list(
        list(
          count = 3,
          label = "3 mo",
          step = "month",
          stepmode = "backward"),
        list(
          count = 6,
          label = "6 mo",
          step = "month",
          stepmode = "backward"),
        list(
          count = 1,
          label = "1 yr",
          step = "year",
          stepmode = "backward"),
        list(
          count = 1,
          label = "YTD",
          step = "year",
          stepmode = "todate"),
        list(step = "all"))),
    
    rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
  
  yaxis = list(title = "Price"))

fig
```

However, now I'd like to create a buttons to select the first year (2018) and second year (2019) separately. Both `stepmode` options seems to define ranges backwards from the last date only, so I'm not really sure how can I specify the range for 2018 year. Is it possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `updatemenu` to select range:

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(ds, x = ~Date)
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~AAPL.Adjusted, name = "Apple")
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(y = ~MSFT.Adjusted, name = "Microsoft")


  rangeselector = list(
    buttons = list(
      list(
        count = 3,
        label = "3 mo",
        step = "month",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 6,
        label = "6 mo",
        step = "month",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 1,
        label = "1 yr",
        step = "year",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 1,
        label = "YTD",
        step = "year",
        stepmode = "todate")))
xaxis = list(rangeselector = rangeselector,
             rangeslider = list(type = "date"))


fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Stock Prices",
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      active = -1,
      type = 'buttons',
      buttons = list(
        list(
          label = '2018',
          method = "relayout",
          args = list(list(xaxis = list(range = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01","2018-12-31"), origin= "1970-1-1"),
                                        rangeselector = rangeselector,
                                        rangeslider = list(type = "date"))))), 
        list(
          label = '2019',
          method = "relayout",
          args = list(list(xaxis = list(range = as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-01","2019-12-31"), origin= "1970-1-1"),
                                        rangeselector = rangeselector,
                                        rangeslider = list(type = "date"))))),
        list(
          label = 'All',
          method = "relayout",
          args = list(list(xaxis = list(range = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01","2019-12-31"), origin= "1970-1-1"),
                                        rangeselector = rangeselector,
                                        rangeslider = list(type = "date")))))
      )
    )
  ),
  xaxis = xaxis,
  
  yaxis = list(title = "Price"))


fig
```

[image]

Comment: @jakes, as `rangeselector`doesn't seem to provide the functionality you're looking for, is the `updatemenu`an acceptable workaround for you?